# Programmatically manage the default Search field in the Help submenu.

Tags: cocoa, menu, menuitem

As far as I understand, the well-known Search menu item (shown below)

[image]

is inserted silently inside a submenu if this is titled "Help".
I am looking for a way to interact with it programmatically (for customisation,
to get rid of it... whatever), but it seems hard to track down. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. What I was looking for is the `helpMenu` property of `NSApplication`.